# Node.js web app crashes when deployed to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

This problem has probably been posted about a dozen times, but I can't find a single fix to my problem.

Here is my code:

```
//////////////////// VARIABLES ////////////////////

//use express
var express = require('express');
//variable to use express
var app = express();
//use the body-parser middleware to handle post data
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
//create a variable for the server
//var server = require('http').Server(app)//

//////////////////// SETUP ////////////////////

//tells express to use ejs as the view/template engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//use express as middleware to serve static pages
app.use('/CSS', express.static('CSS'));
app.use('/images', express.static('images'));

//////////////////// FUNCTIONALITY ////////////////////

//sets index as the default page
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
//serve specified pages
app.get('/:page', function (req, res) {
  res.render(req.params.page);
});

app.post('/custom_rec', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.render('custom_rec', {data: req.body});
});

const host = '0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, host, function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

Here are the relevant logs:

```
2018-10-23T08:42:25.388218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-23T08:42:30.109913+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node ./index.js`
2018-10-23T08:42:33.503841+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-23T08:42:33.525464+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439948+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:549
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439965+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439967+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439968+00:00 app[web.1]:
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439970+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js'
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439972+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439973+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439975+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439976+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
2018-10-23T08:42:33.439978+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Here is my Procfile:

```
web: node ./index.js
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "anirec",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "hidden"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "hidden"
  },
  "homepage": "hidden",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "ejs": "^2.6.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.4"
  }
}
```

Here is an image of my directory:

[image]

The app works using local host.

I've tried having my server listen to 'process.env.PORT'. I've tried taking out "main" in my package.json. I've tried a relative path in my Procfile. I've tried reinstalling node_modules. My Procfile is in the same directory as index.js.

What else am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've also tried restarting the server/dyno. 'Index.js' is also listed when I type 'git ls-files' into my terminal.

Comment: Try `web: node index.js` for your Procfile

Comment: That's what I started out with. I tried it again just now and I get the same issue.

Comment: Is your `index.js` in the correct location? Also note that `/` (root) may change on Heroku.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean when you say the root may change on Heroku. Could you explain?

My index.js is in the same directory as my Procfile (a directory named "AniRec", the root directory where I ran my npm install and git commands).

(I'm sorry if a lot of that info might have been irrelevant. I'm unsure what might count as irrelevant info.)

Comment: Do you have public repo for your app? So we can test heroku deployment...

Comment: I found an issue and posted an answer

Comment: Also your code from index.js is different than you posted here. One more issue you have is the way you listen a port. It should be `process.env.PORT || 5000`, check your index.js file in the repo please.

Comment: Ah, I pushed to heroku but had forgotten to push to github. The code posted here is the one that didn't work. However, the answer that you posted is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have case-sensitive issue, your `Index.js` starts with capital letter, it should be `index.js` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not realize that my Git was case-insensitive. It now makes sense why  'Index.js' is listed when I type 'git ls-files' into my terminal (as opposed to 'index.js'). I've been stuck on this problem for hours. Once again, thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome. Be careful with case sensitivity ;) Good luck!